# Problem with usage of sed in package.json

Tags: npm, sed, package.json

In package.json of a npm project I am using sed in this way:

```
shx sed -i "s/'..\/node_modules\/x\/y\/z\/x.min';/'node_modules\/x\/y\/z\/x.min';/" src/styles/external/application.scss
```

It just print the content of the file with the proper replacement.
When I try this from console without escaping it works properly.
How to made proper escaping in order this to work? I tried also with double escaping - \/
and with another delimiter - @.

Comment: Did you read the documentation for shx? https://www.npmjs.com/package/shx -- they mention this very topic there.

Comment: Yes: "Note: like unix sed, shx sed treats / as a special character, and this must be escaped (as \/ in the shell, or \\/ in package.json) if you intend to use this character in either the regex or replacement string. Do not escape / characters in the file path." - I already wrote - double escaping - \\/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Firstly, escape all forward slashes (`/`) of the pathnames in your pattern with double backslashes, i.e. `\\/`. As mentioned in the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shx) which reads as follows:

   > **Note**: like unix `sed`, `shx sed` treats `/` as a special character, and [this must be escaped](https://github.com/shelljs/shx/issues/169#issuecomment-563013849) (as `\/` in the shell, or `\\/` in `package.json`) if you intend to use this character in either the regex or replacement string. Do **not** escape `/` characters in the file path.
2. Also, encase the pattern given to sed [`s` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/The-_0022s_0022-Command.html) in JSON escaped double quotes, i.e. `\"...\"`

**package.json**

```json
...
"scripts": {
  "replace": "shx sed -i \"s/'..\\/node_modules\\/x\\/y\\/z\\/x.min';/'node_modules\\/x\\/y\\/z\\/x.min';/g\" src/styles/external/application.scss"
                         ^^     ^^             ^^  ^^  ^^  ^^                      ^^  ^^  ^^  ^^          ^^
},
...
```

**Note** The given npm script also includes the `g` flag.

Running `npm run replace` will replace all instances of:

> ```
> '../node_modules/x/y/z/x.min';
> ```

in the contents of the file at `src/styles/external/application.scss` with the following:

> ```
> 'node_modules/x/y/z/x.min';
> ```

Comment: Thanks. I reached the same solution but was thinking "There is a problem" because I get replaced content of the input file in console also.